# Relocate iOS App launch image

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, xcode4

When i add launch image by dragging file into xcode (this file not at project for now) - xcode copy it to root folder of app and use as launch image. (1)

This is good. But the problem - i want that my images was in root/images/launch/Default.png.

If we try to put image to this path, then add this image as resource to project. Now try to select this added image as launch image: drag from xcode file list or click select file on launch image place - result that xcode can't use it because it not in root. (2)

The solutions i found - add image accroding way (1). Then relocate file on hard drive with help of finder. then xcode mark file as missed. click on file and select for them new location. Result - all work.

or

add use way (2) and then add image to copy bundle resourses build phase. in this case xcode automaticaly use this image as launch

So, how i can put image in different folder without this hack ?

ps: sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been tearing my hair out on this one as well.

For completeness, in XCode 4.6 you need to do the following:

1. Clean the project
2. Right-click each launch image and choose 'Delete'
3. Create your folder with your launch images, named
   according to XCode's requirements (i.e. Default.png, Default@2x.png,
   Default-Portrait~ipad.png, Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png etc.
4. Drag the folder into your project and drop it where you need it.

XCode then finds the named images and plugs them in without insisting on moving the launch images to the root of the project.

This is especially useful if you have multiple targets and need different images for each target. Also, if you've used "Duplicate" to create a duplicate project.

Took me 5 days to find this.

NB - This is for XCode 4.6 only - I haven't tackled this on XCode 5 yet.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add image on the project folder
2. Click on the icon box located on the project's summary tab

[image: Icon]

3. There will be a popup with 3 options (Show in finder, delete, add)
4. Choose add option
5. Locate the file in finder
6. Press add button

Comment: Where is this icon box ? Do you mean app icons ? if so - my question was about launch image, not app icon

Comment: @sacred: where you drop the dragged icon file

Comment: sorry i cant find it. can you make screenshot ?

Comment: just a second, i'll upload an image

Comment: I'm now on windows pc, sorry, that's why I couldn't upload an appropriate image. This is from internet :)

Comment: ok. as i see you tell me how to change app icon. but i want use image for launch image. is it clear ?

Comment: double click on the icon adding box, then do it like the steps above

Comment: ok. my image in /Users/sacred/test/test/image/Default-568h@2x_.png

when i try to add it - xcode copy image to /Users/sacred/test
but i want that it was in image folder

Answer (score 0):

as i see - this is normal xcode behaviour.
when we add image to different folder and add this folder to project - xcode automaticaly use image as launch image.
if i try to change this image throw build in launch image view changer - i can use only image in top folder.
also we can use build phase -> copy resource